# Django RawIdWidget with checkboxes

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a raw_field_id with organizations:

> raw_id_fields = ('organizations',)

This displays an input field with ID's of the selected Organizations.

When you click on the magnifier a popup windows opens with all the Organizations listed nicely. You can click one Organization and the ID will be placed into the input field.

Is it possible to use checkboxes to select more than one Organization?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to list Orgnization as checkbox (actually radio button or dorpdown) and pick one among them. Just replace the default widget.

If you mean to pick up more than one item, you may need to check [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField). In a many-to-one relationship, aka ForeignKey, between A and B, one A instance can refs to at most one B instance at any time.

Answer (score 0):

The bad news is there's no easy way to do this.

You would have to subclass the [ManyToManyRawIdWidget](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py) and override at least the `render` method. It would also take further work to create the page that lists the organizations with the checkboxes, with a select button that updates the `organizations` raw id field. Once you did this you would use the [`Meta.widgets`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py) attribute to use your custom widget, instead of using the `raw_id_fields` option.

Comment: I think this will be appreciated by allot of users. Selecting allot of items and place them in the raw_id_fields input with a single click. I don't understand why this is not standard. And another thing is I want to delete one organization i need to know what id it has... oh well